# Pandas filter data to multiple excel files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, xlsxwriter

I have dataframe like as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'customer': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'region': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': rng.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

I would like to do the below

a) filter the data based on `customer` field

b) store each subset in a seperate `.xlsx` with each file carrying the customer name as file name (there should be 3 excel files because we have 3 unique customers which are A, C and D)

I tried the below

```
for cust, v in cdf.groupby(['customer']):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{cust}.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{cust}')
    writer.close()
```

Though files are generated, I get the below error message

> Excel cannot open the file A.xlsx because the file format or extension
> is not valid. Verify that file has been corrupted and that file
> extension matches the format of the file

How can I avoid the error and store data for each customer in seperate excel file with both file and sheet name having customer name

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try to change the engine by `'openpyxl'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine but you can try 2 other solutions: change the engine using `engine='openpyxl'` or use `cdf.to_excel`:

```
for cust, v in cdf.groupby(['customer']):
    v.to_excel(f"{cust}.xlsx", sheet_name=f"{cust}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your excel is Microsoft excel 97 then try this simple step:

import pandas as pd

import xlrd

data = pd.read_html('filename.xls')

Comment: Hi Madhur Dahale, thank you for your time and contribution. Please consider enhancing the content and structure of your answer. Additionally, it appears that your answer may not be correct. I am unclear why `xlrd` was imported but not utilized, and the usage of `read_html` is also unclear. Can you please provide further clarification?